# Trigger to compare cost MySQL

Tags: mysql, database-trigger

I am new in MySQL.
I want to create a trigger that compares the cost in the tender table with the request table, if the cost in the tender table is bigger than the cost in request table will give a static score in the KPI table.

tender table (ID, Name, cost)

request table(ID, Name, Estimated_cost, supplier_ID)

KPI table(ID, cost)

I get the following error when I insert a row in request table:

```
#1146 - Table 'rozana_supplier.inserted' doesn't exist
```

How can I correct the syntax error?

```
     BEGIN 
SET @cost1=(SELECT tender_request.Cost FROM inserted where tender_request.TenderID=tender.Tender_ID); 
SET @cost2=(SELECT tender.Estimated_cost FROM inserted where tender_request.TenderID=tender.Tender_ID); 
IF(@cost2>@cost1)  then 
 UPDATE `kpi` set Cost=10 WHERE `kpi`.KPI_ID=`supplier performance`.KPIID and `supplier performance`.TenderID=tender.Tender_ID ; 
 END IF;
END
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: Please can you check it again

Comment: You refer to "SQL Server" several times in your question (and in the tags). Which is the name of a specific SQL product from Microsoft. But the error message makes it clear that you're actually working with MySQL.

Comment: can you check it again please, and give me an answer please :(

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html

Comment: The error is mysql but the code is nothing like mysql are you trying to convert from sql server to mysql? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-trigger.html

Comment: Can you check it again

Comment: My quess is you are working from a sql server tutorial and trying to use that in mysql, Unfortunately sql server and mysql are very different in the way they have implemented triggers - mysql does not have inserted temporary tables for example. I suggest you work through mysql specific examples.